# Which flash player does this website uses

Tags: flash, html, javascript, web-development

I want to know which flash player this website is using
http://www.videochaska.com/video/thriller/adaalat/chand-par-hatiya-part02/10238

How are they streaming video; I do not see any where rtmp protocol in the embedded javascript.

Comment: I understand but if none of the answers work how can I accept

Comment: Take a look at the FAQ this question is off topic here on SuperUser, maybe it could be migrated to some place else, but the question might have to be improved before that.

Answer (score 1):

Examining the video's `<object>` tag and the surrounding HTML comments reveals that they're using one of the [Brightcove Media Solutions](http://www.brightcove.com/en/solutions).

Comment: ok so does that mean that they are streaming the video as far as I know video streaming is a different thing which in this case is not happening if I directly want to download the file is it possible I do not want a tool to do so any web link in the source if you can observe....

Comment: I use chrome and this link shows for firefox http://mcchrystals.wordpress.com/2008/12/30/firefox-download-brightcove-videos/